# JQuery - get confused when to use function() or function(e)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new in learning JS. I understand it's a shorthand for event. When will I know when to use function() or function(e)?

I attached 2 sets of code that I read on the book here or if you have a better one to help me understand. Please, welcome. Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
  var ids=";
  var $1istitems = $( '1i');

  $listltems.on('mouseover click', function()
                ids= this.id;
                $listltems.children('span').remove();
  $(this).append(' <span class="priori ty">' +ids+ '</span>');
} ) ;

$listltems.on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).children( ' span').remove();
} ) ;
} ) ;

//———————————————————————————————

$(function() {
  $(' l i ') .on('cli ck' function(e)
  $( ' l i span').remove () ;
  var dat e = new Date() ;
  date.setTime(e .timeStamp);
  var clicked= dat e . toDateString() ;
  $(this) .append('<span class="date"> ' +clicked+ ' ' + e.type + '</ span>' );
} ) ;
} ) ;
```

Comment: You'll use `function(e)` whenever you need to use `e` inside the function. Otherwise you can leave it out.

Comment: Which is a shorthand for event?

Comment: If you need to know something from an event (for example during a `keypress()` function, in order to get the key), you need to put `event` or `e` in parameters. Otherwise, you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on your use case, you need to define the parameter only if you need to access an event property like `event.target` or do actions like stopping propagation or preventing default action.

Answer (score 0):

The `e` or `event` comes in handy for a lot of things. For example, you can prevent defaults behaviors such as a link redirecting to an url, or a form being submit by using `e.preventDefault()`, you can stop the propagation/bubbling of the event to the parent DOM elements with `e.stopPropagation()`. The event holds the target where the event was fired, if you are attaching a `keypress` or any other keyboard interaction event, you can get the pressed key code, whether or not the user has pressed shift/control keys. Hope this clears some things out for you, you should read more as this explanation is simply an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, e stands for jQuery event object

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

It must be passed to the function only in case if it's methods required inside of that function. And since event passed as function argument, it can be named as you wish so.